# Getting strange errors when installing visual studio 2015 community rc

Tags: installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I have windows 7 x64 on my laptop, few days ago i tried to install visual studio 2015 community rc but i get flowing error when installer tries to install ".NET Framework 4.6 rc" :

```
Microsoft .NET framework 4.6 rc
Fatal error during installation.

Visual c++ library Redist resource package
Package failed.
```

And last lines in setup log files are:

```
[189C:1670][2015-06-10T18:20:08]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[189C:1670][2015-06-10T18:20:08]i000: MUX:  Format Message Failed: 317
[189C:1670][2015-06-10T18:20:08]i000: MUX:  Format Message Failed: 317
[189C:1670][2015-06-10T18:20:08]i399: Apply complete, result: 0xc0000421,     restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

I download ".NET framework 4.6 rc" and tried to install it out of visual studio but this time i get this problem:

```
1.he setup cannot run in compatibility mode.
2.The .NET Framework 4.6 redistributable does not apply to this operating system. Please download the .NET Framework 4.6 for your operating system from the <A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=513370">Microsoft Download Center.
```

But the downloaded package is for windows 7 and windows 8 and my windows is 7 edition.

And i have a problem in my windows and i don't know how to solve the problem, some times when i want to install new applications such as firefox the installer app exits automatically without any error messages, You know in Visual studio's iso file there is packages such as sql server express, .NET Framework 4.6 rc and others, when i try to install this packages manually with their .msi files the installer has been crashed and exit without any message.

Comment: When i tried to install VS 2015 Community on Windows-7 32 bit i get the error: "This version of Visual Studio required a computer with a newer version of windows". Anybody knows any workaround?

Comment: @isaeid I had the exact same error. Further research indicated a lack of space on the installation partition. After I freed up more than 20GB, reran the installer and it worked perfectly.